# In "Boston Legal," how can some of the clients afford to pay their fees?

Tags: boston-legal

All the lead characters are employed by a prominent Boston law firm that deals in multi-million-dollar lawsuits and takes on huge corporations. The expenses must be through the roof, not to mention the lawyers' salaries and benefits.

Meanwhile, their clients come from every walk of life, and some of them (many of them, in fact) live from paycheck to paycheck, including the ones against whom criminal charges are brought.

My question is: how can those clients afford the services, which can cost tens of thousands (or hundreds of thousands) of dollars?

Comment: Is it possible they do this *pro bono*?

Comment: @OldPadawan: As in, 90% of all cases? I don't think so.

Comment: No-Win-No-Fee agreements?  The law firm takes a significant cut of the win?

Comment: @iandotkelly: In a criminal case? There's no money for the winner.

Comment: It's a TV show the economics take a back seat to plot and drama. This is the case in the majority of "law" shows.

Comment: @Paulie_D: In other words, this quote (from Tom Wolfe's Bonfire of the Vanities) is correct: "The starched dandy who sat before him
had a New York street accent, full of dropped consonants
and tortured vowels. Nevertheless, he had lifted Sherman’s
spirits a notch or two by indicating that he knew Sherman
was new to the world of criminal law and that he existed on
a plateau far above it. “What sort of case?” asked
Sherman. “Drugs. Who else can afford a trial lawyer for
eight weeks?” - Plus some very wealthy people. Yes?

Comment: No. Just that how they get paid is irrelevant unless it's part of the plot for TV purposes

Comment: @Paulie_D: I beg to differ. That's like saying it's irrelevant how a school teacher gets to live in a Manhattan duplex and own a Bentley and a private jet. It's just not plausible. Plots are supposed to be plausible.

Comment: You don't watch a lot of TV then? Sorry, I joke, but it's not important to the plot so it's not mentioned. As I said this is common in TV law shows. Perhaps it's a pro bono case, perhaps they do it for the TV/movie rights but frankly it's not important. If you can't suspend your disbelief then these shows aren't for you.

Comment: @Paulie_D: You're right, I don't. But that's hardly the point. (Oh, and if you mean Friends: the girls' apartment is a bit of a stretch, yes, but ... but ... as the authors have explained numerous times (sounding apologetic), there's rent control and a grandmother).